# Maintain jquery .css action after page refirects to clicked link

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink

I have a site with a number of links. 
I want to always ensure the user knows what page he or she is by changing the color of the active link to red and a few more css properties.
So i came up with the following

```
$('ul.nav li a').click(function()
{
    $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

So it works... kinds, only until the webpage redirects to the clicked link. Question is, how do i maintain the changes made using jquery after the page loads.

Thanks

Comment: You necessary save options.. for instance using [cookie][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

First of all I clearly wouldn't do this using only javascript. But if you can't change anything serverside, you could store the

```
href
```

of the link you just clicked in the localStorage and read it on page load to initialize the color on the right link.

Here is a jsFiddle to illustrate : http://jsfiddle.net/5VLcL/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this client side (using jQuery), you could check that the `href` is in the URL:

`if (pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf(thisHref) >= 0)`

Here's a fiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/phjCn/